# Why is “set autoindent” in my ~/.vimrc ignored when I open a file?

Tags: vimrc

I have set autoindentation, but vim somehow ignores it because `:set autoindent?` says `noautoindent` however the last file to have set autoindent is really my vimrc file according to `:verbose set autoindent?`

```
noautoindent
        Last set from ~/myScripts/.vim/vimrc line 10
```

However `set autoindent` is really in my vimrc file :

```
$ grep -n autoindent ~/myScripts/.vim/vimrc
10:set autoindent
```

EDIT0 : Lines between 9 and 11 of my `~/myScripts/.vim/vimrc` file :

```
$ sed -n 9,11p ~/myScripts/.vim/vimrc
set nohls
set autoindent
set noexpandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

EDIT1 : `~/.vim/vimrc` is pointing to my `~/myScripts/.vim/vimrc` :

```
$ readlink -f ~/.vim/vimrc
/home/sebastien/myScripts/.vim/vimrc
```

EDIT2: Thanks to filbranden, it seems that `paste` and `autoindent` are mutually exclusive :

> The 'autoindent' option is reset when the 'paste' option is set and
>           restored when 'paste' is reset.

Here's what I had in my `~/myScripts/.vim/vimrc` :

```
$ egrep -n "^set ((no)?autoindent|(no)?paste)" ~/myScripts/.vim/vimrc
10:set autoindent
67:set paste
```

Comment: What's on line 11? Is it something starting with `\!` or something like that?

Comment: @filbranden See my EDIT0

Comment: Odd... How are you sourcing your vimrc from that file? Can you reproduce that with a one-line vimrc file with only that line?

Comment: @filbranden See my EDIT1

Comment: Is `$HOME` set to something else in Vim? What happens if you open `~/myScripts/.vim/vimrc` inside Vim? Is that the same file? Yeah I'm grasping at straws here, but I really can't explain why this would happen... Like I mentioned, try to see if dropping stuff from your vimrc or disabling plug-ins will still make it reproduce the issue.

Comment: @filbranden `:echo $HOME` says `/home/sebastien`. Opening `~/myScripts/.vim/vimrc` works fine.

Comment: I guess you have `:set paste?` enabled! Do `:set nopaste` and that should restore autoindent to its original state!

Comment: @filbranden Oh I see, help autoindent says that autoindent and paste are mutually exclusive which seems logical. I remember that on some systems I had to `set noautoindent` before pasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening due to `:set paste`.

As [`:help 'autoindent'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27autoindent%27) says:

> The `'autoindent'` option is reset when the `'paste'` option is set and restored when 'paste' is reset.

It turns out this affects the way `:set ai?` reports the setting, even though `:verbose` still keeps showing the source for the setting coming from the same line:

```
:verbose set ai?
  autoindent
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vim-sensible/plugin/sensible.vim line 20
:set paste
:verbose set ai?
noautoindent
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vim-sensible/plugin/sensible.vim line 20
```

So just make sure you don't have `'paste'` enabled. It shouldn't be enabled during normal operation anyways...

---

If you want a helper to manage enabling `'paste'` when you're pasting external text into Vim, I recommend [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) which defines a `yop` mapping (together with `[op` and `]op`). From [`:help yop`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/4afbe5ebf32ad85341b4c02b0e1d8ca96a64c561/doc/unimpaired.txt#L108,L113):

> A toggle has not been provided for `'paste'` because the typical use case of
>   wrapping of a solitary insertion is inefficient:  You toggle twice, but
>   you only paste once (YOPO). Instead, press `[op`, `]op`, or `yop` to invoke `O`,
>   `o`, or `0C` with `'paste'` already set.  **Leaving insert mode sets `'nopaste'`
>   automatically.**